# Orchard CMS 1.8 Page Title not showing

Tags: title, orchardcms-1.8

It is my understanding that the default Core\Shapes\Views\Document.cshtml file has code to retrieve the page ("string title = Convert.ToString(Model.Title);") and site title  below. However the value is blank even though titles have been entered into the CMS for each page. The "site title" gets displayed though.

Is this a bug? How can I retrieve the page's title to be included in the tag?

Thanks in advance!

```
.
.
.

string title = Convert.ToString(Model.Title);
string siteName = Convert.ToString(WorkContext.CurrentSite.SiteName);
.
.
.

<title>@Html.Title(title, siteName)</title> 
@Display(Model.Head)
```